# For transfering bulk data in thousands using web service , which data transfer to be used?

Tags: webservices

I have requirement to transfer very heavy data from one system to another using web services. So in order to transfer data as expected wth no performance issue which data transfer should I use?
SOAP/REST?

Answer (score 1):

The following are the differences between SOAP and REST API.
SOAP has been preferred for services within the enterprise and
REST has been preferred for services that are exposed as public APIs.

The advantage of REST API lies with performance:

- with better cache support
- lightweight requests and responses, and easier response parsing
- reduces network traffic.

REST API provides a powerful, convenient, and simple REST-based Web services interface for interacting with Salesforce. Its advantages include ease of integration and development, and it’s an excellent choice of technology for use with mobile applications and Web projects.

You might also wanna explore **Bulk API** .

TO get the details on which API to use and when please go throught the official salesforce documentation below :
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm